# Is there any example or resource explaining/showing code from High-level to Low-level to deep down Machine code?

Tags: low-level, flowchart, high-level, machine-code

I have been searching for an example over the internet that shows any operation like saving a file or drawing anything in UI or any other sort that shows the implementation from High-leve language code to Low-level code to deep down machine level code.

The basic idea is to explain the computer working in a nutshell. Like, in high-level laguage we write `int c= int a + int b` which is compiled into low-level code `IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: ldarg.2 IL_0003: add` and then to machine level code.

Any example or code flowchart from high-leve language to deep down machine code will be helpful.

Comment: The short answer is there's a reason I spent four years studying computer science at college. It takes a while to get through all of those layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) is the only tool can do such deep inspection throughout software stack that I know of. You may find this example of tracing [from PHP all the way to OS kernel](http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/2005/08/05/dtrace-and-php-demonstrated/) useful.

It was originally developed at Sun Microsystems as one of key new features for Solaris 10. It has been ported to Mac OS X and FreeBSD since then. A breakthrough if you ask me.

Comment: DTrace is brilliant.